# How to reduce execution time of my query in Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance

I extracted those table names from different views and functions. Execution time takes 1day+ to finish. My goal is to reduce the time from 1day to 30minutes or less. My boss suggested me to fine tuned all the queries inside the views under views. Any tips or suggestions on how to reduce the time?

**Query**

```
SELECT to_char(con.originalstartdate, 'MM/DD/YY') TXNDATEIN,
       to_char(con.originalstartdate, 'HH24:MI:SS') TIMEIN,
       to_char(CON.LASTACTIVITYDATE, 'MM/DD/YY') TXNDATEOUT,
       to_char(con.lastactivitydate, 'HH24:MI:SS') TIMEOUT,
       pack.mes_packagename, prodfam.productfamilyname,
       con.containername RELATEDCONTNAME, shd.qty QTYIN, 
       con.qty QTYOUT, qtyhist.qty, lossrea.lossreasonname,
       resdef.resourcename WS, emp.fullname EMPLOYEENAME,
       oprtn.operationname, hml.txndate,
       (   SELECT GET_DIFFUSION_CONTAINER_APP(con.containername) 
           FROM DUAL) AS DIFFUSION
FROM container con, package pack, productfamily prodfam, 
     lossreason lossrea, resourcedef resdef, employee emp, 
     operation oprtn, qtyhistory qtyhist, splithistorydetails shd,
     historymainline hml
where con.lastactivitydate >=  to_date('06/23/2014 6:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')
and con.lastactivitydate < to_date('06/24/2014 6:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')
and hml.txndate >= to_date('06/23/2014 6:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS') 
and to_char(hml.txndate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') <= to_char(con.lastactivitydate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
ORDER BY RELATEDCONTNAME;
```

**ORIGINAL QUERY**

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET COLSEP ,
SET PAGES 0
SET LINESIZE 1000
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET UNDERLINE OFF
SET VER OFF

column NCURRENT NEW_VALUE VFILE NOPRINT
column NYEST NEW_VALUE VFILE2  
column NNOW NEW_VALUE VFILE3  
column NCURRENTYEAR NEW_VALUE VFILE4  
column WEEKCODE NEW_VALUE VFILE5 

select to_char(sysdate -2 , 'RRRR-MM-DD')||' 06:00:00' NYEST
--select '2013-05-18 12:00:00' NYEST
from dual;

select to_char(sysdate-1, 'RRRR-MM-DD')||' 06:00:00' NNOW
--select '2013-05-19 12:00:00' NNOW
from dual;

select to_char(sysdate, 'RRRR') NCURRENTYEAR
from dual;

select 'FName_'||to_char(sysdate-1, 'MONDDRRRR')||'.csv' NCURRENT
from dual;

spool [Filepath];

select 
       TXNDATEIN||','||TIMEIN||','||TXNDATEOUT||','||TIMEOUT||','||  MES_PACKAGENAME||','||MINICOMPANYNAME||','||PRODUCTFAMILYNAME||','||RELATEDCONTNAME||','||
       QTYIN||','||QTYOUT||','||QTY||','||LOSSREASONNAME||','||WS||','||REPLACE(EMPLOYEENAME,',',' ')||','||OPERATIONNAME||','||
       (SELECT GET_DIFFUSION_CONTAINER_APP(RELATEDCONTNAME) FROM DUAL) AS DIFFUSION
from 
 vw_power_overallyield_batchfe
where 
txndate >=  to_date('&&VFILE2', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
and txndate < to_date('&&VFILE3', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
and scraptxndate >= to_date('&&VFILE2', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') 
and to_char(scraptxndate, 'MM/DD/YY') <= TXNDATEOUT 
ORDER BY RELATEDCONTNAME;
spool off;
exit
```

- "vw_power_overallyield_batchfe" has many views

**EXPLAIN PLAN**

```
    PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                          |    18E|    15E|       |    18E  (0)|
|   1 |  FAST DUAL                             |                          |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)|
|   2 |  SORT ORDER BY                         |                          |    18E|    15E|    15E|    18E  (0)|
|   3 |   MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                 |                          |    18E|    15E|       |    18E  (0)|
|   4 |    MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                |                          |    18E|    15E|       |    18E  (0)|
|   5 |     MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN               |                          |    18E|    15E|       |   204P  (1)|
|   6 |      MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN              |                          |    54T|  5457T|       |   521G  (1)|
|   7 |       MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN             |                          |    84G|  7259G|       |   942M  (1)|
|   8 |        MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN            |                          |    17M|  1258M|       |   210K  (1)|
|   9 |         MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN           |                          |  8713 |   536K|       |    87   (3)|
|  10 |          MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN          |                          |    16 |   816 |       |    16  (13)|
|  11 |           MERGE JOIN                   |                          |     1 |    43 |       |    13  (16)|
|  12 |            SORT JOIN                   |                          |     3 |    24 |       |     5  (20)|
|* 13 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN           | HISTORYMLBYTXNDATEANDRES |     3 |    24 |       |     4   (0)|
|* 14 |            SORT JOIN                   |                          |     4 |   140 |       |     8  (13)|
|  15 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CONTAINER                |     4 |   140 |       |     7   (0)|
|* 16 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN          | CONTAINERBYLADATE        |     5 |       |       |     3   (0)|
|  17 |           BUFFER SORT                  |                          |    25 |   200 |       |     9  (23)|
|  18 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL           | PACKAGE                  |    25 |   200 |       |     3   (0)|
|  19 |          BUFFER SORT                   |                          |   552 |  6624 |       |    84   (3)|
|  20 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL            | RESOURCEDEF              |   552 |  6624 |       |     4   (0)|
|  21 |         BUFFER SORT                    |                          |  2020 | 24240 |       |   210K  (1)|
|  22 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL             | PRODUCTFAMILY            |  2020 | 24240 |       |    24   (0)|
|  23 |        BUFFER SORT                     |                          |  4814 | 81838 |       |   942M  (1)|
|  24 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL              | EMPLOYEE                 |  4814 | 81838 |       |    54   (2)|
|  25 |       BUFFER SORT                      |                          |   638 | 12122 |       |   521G  (1)|
|  26 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL               | OPERATION                |   638 | 12122 |       |     6   (0)|
|  27 |      BUFFER SORT                       |                          |   411K|  2009K|       |   204P  (1)|
|  28 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                | SPLITHISTORYDETAILS      |   411K|  2009K|       |  3785   (1)|
|  29 |     BUFFER SORT                        |                          |  1171K|  5720K|       |    18E  (0)|
|  30 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | QTYHISTORY               |  1171K|  5720K|       |  4690   (1)|
|  31 |    BUFFER SORT                         |                          |  1382 | 13820 |       |    18E  (0)|
|  32 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | LOSSREASON               |  1382 | 13820 |       |     4   (0)|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

  13 - access("HML"."TXNDATE">=TO_DATE(' 2014-06-23 06:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
              "HML"."TXNDATE" IS NOT NULL)
  14 - access(TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("HML"."TXNDATE"),'MM/DD/YYYY')<=TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("CON".
              "LASTACTIVITYDATE"),'MM/DD/YYYY'))
       filter(TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("HML"."TXNDATE"),'MM/DD/YYYY')<=TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("CON".
              "LASTACTIVITYDATE"),'MM/DD/YYYY'))
  16 - access("CON"."LASTACTIVITYDATE">=TO_DATE(' 2014-06-23 06:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
              "CON"."LASTACTIVITYDATE"<TO_DATE(' 2014-06-24 06:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))

Note
-----
   - 'PLAN_TABLE' is old version

enter code here
```

Comment: Hard to say looking only on the query. Please post the explain plan (run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR the_query` and then run `SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.display)` and copy-paste resuts of the last command. Also definions of all views might be helpful. On thihg that is obvious - you are joining a bunch of tables/views without join conditions, and this produces a cross join.

Comment: @kordirko actually my task is speed up the execution of the query. i think the main cause why it took long to retrieve data is because it has many view and subview. now i need to know name of the fields because VIEWS only give me name of alias. hope you can help me

Comment: Your query involves 10 tables.  It has, at best, one join condition (one that I doubt is correct but it's at least a condition).  Unless you want to do a 9-table Cartesian join, which I'm surprised isn't blowing out your `temp` tablespace, you're missing at least 8 join conditions.

Comment: You join 10 tables but you have only 1 join condition - at this condition uses even a function.

Comment: @JustinCave Yeah, you're right, at the end of the execution, there is an error displaying about temp tablespace. Would you mind showing me how to revise my query?

Comment: You'd have to tell us how your tables relate to each other.  If you're going to use the old style join syntax that you appear to be trying to use rather than the SQL 99 join syntax, you'd need at least 8 predicates in your `where` clause that relate one table to another.  I'm willing to wager that the one join condition you have relating `hml` and `con` is incorrect-- I can't imagine that you want to do a comparison using character semantics with that date format rather than using date semantics for the comparison.

Comment: @paulooooo you wrote `vw_power_overallyield_batchfe has many views`. It means that the performance problem is in `vw_power_overallyield_batchfe` and in definitions of these views. They are slow, not your query. **No one is able to give any help** without looking at these views, or at least at the explain plan (I wrote how to generate the explain plan in my first comment).

Comment: @JustinCave I've posted the explain plan of my query

Comment: I think that the problem is not the performance, but the result. I don't know what the query was expected to retrieve but I'm almost sure that if it would complete it would extract wrong data.
Until you won't be able to put all the join conditions I think that nobody can help you. You are posting a query plan for a wrong query then it's pointless.
Analyze your schema and follow the Thorsten's advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has been given in the comments already: You are cross-joining your tables.

First you are taking all record from table `Container` in a certain date range. Let's say that's 200 records. Then you take all records from table `package`. Let's say this table contains 300 records. You combine all records, which gives you 300 x 200 = 60000 records. Then you take the next table and multiply again, ...

What one would expect is that the tables are related somehow and you would hence use these relations. Let's say that each package resides in a container. Therefore each package record would have a container ID. You don't want to join all packages to all containers, but each package to the one container it belongs to:

```
FROM container con 
JOIN package pack ON pack.container_id = con.id
```

You *could* do this also as

```
FROM container con, package pack 
WHERE pack.container_id = con.id
```

but you shouldn't. This error-prone implicit join syntax was replaced more than twenty years ago by the explicit joins mentioned above. If you had used

```
FROM container con 
JOIN package pack
```

without the ON clause, then the DBMS would have noticed your mistake and told you to join the records properly rather then executig the nonsensical query.

---

EDIT: As to the original query you posted in your edit, make sure that all tables in vw_power_overallyield_batchfe view are properly joined and you have indexes on the linking columns. Then there is little you can do. It may help to have indexes on the date columns, as the DBMS may decide to use a range index scan then. You can also try to execute the query parallelized (with a PARRALLEL HINT).

The line `to_char(scraptxndate, 'MM/DD/YY') <= TXNDATEOUT` looks suspicious, btw. '12/31/14' would be greater than '01/01/15' for instance. That doesn't seem to make sense. Don't you rather want to compare dates, i.e. `scraptxndate <= to_date(TXNDATEOUT,'MM/DD/YY')`?